# typed.js how to make text editable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make the text as on the home page https://laracasts.com/
use for this library
https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/
Question 
How do I make when I click on text the animation stops and I can write my text
here is my code

```
 <h1>
 <span  class="header-title-accent" id="typed" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" > Front-end Developer</span>
</h1>
<script>
              $('document').ready(function(){
                var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
                    strings: ['First ^1000 sentence.', 'Second sentence.'],
                    backSpeed:50,
                    typeSpeed:60,
                    cursorChar: '|||',                       
                });
            });
          </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 2 listeners on the input field to `start()` & `stop()` the Typed instance on `blur` & `focus` respectively. See the docs for more info: https://mattboldt.github.io/typed.js/docs/#typed

Example:

```
$('#typed').on('focus', function(e) {
  typed.stop();
});
   
// You may not need/want this one...
$('#typed').on('blur', function(e) {
  typed.start();
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sforsberg/pen/eYdMLXO)